# Excel VBA Formula on next row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I have a question, I have an excel sheet where data gets imputed in a UserForm then after inputting that data it goes to the next.

My question is I need to put this formula in Column A2

`=IF(B2="","",IF(ISBLANK(I2()),"OPEN","CLOSED"))`

and go to the next row for example the next row A3 input

`=IF(B3="","",IF(ISBLANK(I3()),"OPEN","CLOSED"))`

and so on and on, if it makes any sense.

Thanks in Advance.

Edit: Code is below to input data into next available row

```
'Submit MR and fill next available row in MR workbook
Private Sub buttonSend_Click()

Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lValue As Date

Set ws = Worksheets("Maintance Report")
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
'Submit data
With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.textName.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.comboDepartment.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.comboPriority.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 6).Value = Me.textDescription.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Now

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe it will be easily to understand if you include a couple of pictures so that we can see the context better

Comment: Please show the code you are using to add the data to the sheet

Comment: edit with code to input data into next row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
With .Range("A3")
    .Formula = Replace("=IF(B#="""","""",IF(ISBLANK(I#()),""OPEN"",""CLOSED""))", _
                       "#", .Row)
End With
```